# Is there any way to retrieve a list of open session objects from a session factory in nHibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, session

I would like to be able to query the session factory for a list of all sessions which were created and are still open.  It seems like this should be tracked somewhere, even if it is not public or directly accessible from the factory.

Comment: You can make an own implementation of your session factory. If a session is requested you add it to a session list. If it closes you remove it from the list.

Comment: Er..I can kind of see how that would work, basically create a hash table of "running" sessionid's when I request a session.  Store the session itself as the object referenced by that key.   That would be pretty easy, but it just seems messy.  I would have to remove the session from the hash table when the session ends. Since I am not using session per request, I would really like a cleaner implementation. I was hoping I could simply query the _sessionfactory in some way for open sessions, but I do appreciate the input @peer.

Comment: Does NH profiler do this?  I've never used it but it's a popular tool for tracking what NH is doing.

Comment: @Cole Hey Cole, I have used NH Prof quite a bit, it is a great tool.  It sits and monitors the activity and you can see the sessions open and see the sql activity associated with each one, but I am not sure how the NH monitoring dll hooks into the workflow, or if that would give me exactly what I need.   Thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are incorrectly framing your question (an XY Problem).

Why would you need to know, from a central place, which sessions are still open?

Is your application leaking resources? Do you need performance statistics?

I suggest that you edit your question to reflect the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am trying to think outside the box, and use nhibernate in a different pattern than session per request, and do it in a way that doesn't make more work in the long run. I feel my question is valid.

Comment: @DavidC: I didn't say it wasn't valid. Please explain how you are trying to use it and we'll be able to help. Otherwise, the best I can give you is "just keep track of them yourself from the class that is in charge of opening sessions, create it if you don't have one"